# Combine multiple columns to one list column

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to combine multiple columns to one list column in a data.table in R. Example:

```r
require(data.table)

dt = data.table(col1 = LETTERS[1:5],
                col2 = rep('test', 5),
                col3 = c('hello', 'yes', 'no', 'maybe', 'why'))
```

**Q:** How can I combine `col2` and `col3` into a list column?

What I've tried so far:

```r
cols = c('col2', 'col3')
dt[ , col4 := paste0(.SD, collapse = ', '), .SDcols = cols,
    by = 1:nrow(dt) ] # paste's them together
dt[ , col4 := c(.SD), .SDcols = cols,
    by = 1:nrow(dt) ] # drops col3
dt[ , col4 := lapply(.SD, c), .SDcols = cols,
    by = 1:nrow(dt) ] # drops col3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `data.table`'s `transpose` function.

```
library(data.table)
cols = c('col2', 'col3')

dt[ , col4 := lapply(transpose(.SD), c), .SDcols = cols] 
dt
#   col1 col2  col3       col4
#1:    A test hello test,hello
#2:    B test   yes   test,yes
#3:    C test    no    test,no
#4:    D test maybe test,maybe
#5:    E test   why   test,why

class(dt$col4)
#[1] "list"
```

Comment: May I ask `.SD` represents for?

Comment: `.SD` represents subset of data. It consists of columns specified in `cols`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
dt[, col4 := do.call(paste, c(.SD, sep = ", ")), .SDcols = col2:col3]
```